# CSS is not applying & images are not loading properly after moving to new server - Magento 1.9

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.9

I have just moved a Magento ( v 1.9 ) store to a new server. Everything started working after changing database and base_url in core_config_data table. But theme is not applying.

Though I can see stylesheet is loaded in the resources tab in chrome and I can access the file by entering the url in browser.

like http://abcd.com/skin/frontend/default/em0089/css/styles.css

[image]

However I can access the admin panel without any problem.

Thank you.

Comment: try to remove var folder from root

Comment: Hi @DhavalPatel have deleted all the contents in var directory, should i also remove var directory ?

Comment: It's likely a permissions problem on your new server I would guess (I've had this before). Follow the steps in this: [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/file-and-folder-permissions-for-magento-setup](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/file-and-folder-permissions-for-magento-setup)

Comment: please share site link here..

Comment: @DhavalPatel website is http://indowesternpublishers.com/

Comment: admin link is working...login admin and cache and reindexed
http://indowesternpublishers.com/admin

Comment: if permission issue than run magento-cleanup.php

Comment: @DhavalPatel have clear cache and re index from admin panel but no success

Comment: @DevendraVerma Could you share your site url?

Comment: @Muk website link is http://indowesternpublishers.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?